# Site enters Cookieless state in .NET 4.0 App

Tags: .net, viewstate

Every once in a while I notice my site goes into a cookieless state, although I don't have this option specified in my web.config. In addition my ASP.NET Menu control shows all the menu items although I have specific roles attached to some menu items.

It seems the site is still secure because if the user clicks on a menu item thats role specific it will redirect them to the login page.

I also noticed in Elmah there are a lot of Invalid Viewstate error messages on my registration and login pages. I assumed I am being hacked. Any tips on how to prevent this?

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if this relates to an AppPool recycle. Also: how many servers do you have? 1 or more than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"although I don't have this option specified in my web.config. "

Are you sure?  Because what you are describing sure sounds like this mode:

```
<sessionState  cookieless="AutoDetect"
```

Comment: I don't have that node specified in my web.config